# Unable to load image into Canvas using React and Nextjs

Tags: reactjs, image, canvas, next.js

I have tried to load an image into my canvas element within my react component. I have tried loading a URL, I have tried loading from the folders with in my local repositories, I have tried different syntax forms to load the image, all to no avail.

The only "progress" I have made is that I am no longer getting an error in the console, however, the image is still not viewable in my app.

This is the component.

```
import React, { useRef, useEffect } from 'react';
import cn from 'classnames';
import styles from './styles.module.scss';



const Introduction = ({ info }) => {
  

  const canvasRef = useRef(null);

  useEffect(() => {
    const canvas = canvasRef.current;
    const context = canvas.getContext('2d');
    const image = new Image();
    image.src = 'https://i.imgur.com/CGiZRrB.png'

    image.onload = () => {
      context.drawImage(image, 0, 0)
    }

  }, []);

  return (
    <div className={cn('app_bg', 'app_wrapper', 'section_padding')} id='intro'>
      <div /*className={cn('app_wrapper_img','app_wrapper_img_reverse')}*/>
        <div /*className={cn(styles.wrapper_img, 'img_padding')}*/ >
          <canvas
            ref={canvasRef} width={400} height={400}
          />
        </div>
    </div>
    <div className='app_wrapper_info'>
      <h1>{info?.metadata?.section}</h1>
        <h1 className='headtext_cormorant'>{info?.metadata?.title}</h1>
        <div className={styles.intro_content}>
          <div className={styles.intro_content_quote}>
            <p className='opensans'>{info?.metadata?.intro}</p>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div className={styles.intro_sign}>
          <p>{info?.metadata?.sub_info}</p>
          <p className='opensans'>Chef & Founder</p>
          {/*<Image width={200} height={100} src={images?.sign} alt='sign_image' objectFit='contain' />*/}
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  )
}

export default Introduction;
```

When I load the app, the app loads but the image is not there. Unlike before when I tried other methods, I am no longer getting any errors. Except one unrelated error pretaining to "href" which was alway there before I even began working on the canvas.

I know the canvas is loading because there is an empty block of space where I put the canvas in my component, however, no image.

I was expecting the image to load and be viewable in the browser. I have tried importing the image from my src/assets folder and my public folder too but neither works. Right now I'm importing the image as a URL.

Answer (score 0):

Your code is actually working fine but the image you are using is not showing for some reason. When I try a different image source, the `canvas` loads the image properly.

This is the image I tried: https://loremflickr.com/cache/resized/65535_52461676408_4442828f69_320_240_nofilter.jpg

And below is the code:

```
import * as React from 'react';
import { useEffect, useRef } from 'react';

export default function App() {
  const canvasRef = useRef(null);

  useEffect(() => {
    const canvas = canvasRef.current;
    const context = canvas.getContext('2d');
    const image = new Image();
    image.src =
      'https://loremflickr.com/cache/resized/65535_52461676408_4442828f69_320_240_nofilter.jpg';

    image.onload = () => {
      context.drawImage(image, 0, 0);
    };
  }, []);

  return <canvas ref={canvasRef} width={400} height={400} />;
}
```

Comment: What do you think the reason is? My image is a PNG image, and I also used the free Adobe background remover tool to remove the background of my image. Any ideas? I also just uploaded the image to Imgur today. Thank you for helping me debug!

Comment: You're welcome! It might be the canvas size "400" is much smaller than your image. I just tried to change the canvas width and height to "3072" and was able to see your image "https://i.imgur.com/CGiZRrB.png"